# summary plot with FastTreeSHAP

Tags: python, shap

I fitted a random forest classifier, and wanted to use the `FastTreeSHAP` to understand predictors contribution to model predictions.

```py
import fasttreeshap

explainer = fasttreeshap.TreeExplainer(model, algorithm='auto' ,n_jobs=-1)
shap_values = explainer(X_test).values

shap_values.shape
(40682, 24, 5)

# plotting
fasttreeshap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_test, plot_type = 'bar')
```

However, this produces an interaction plot instead (see below).

[image]

**Required**

A bar plot showing predictors' contribution, such as example in figure below (from `FastTreeSHAP` docs).

[image]

Is `FastTreeSHAP`'s `summary_plot()` different from that of `SHAP`, or did something change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# imports
import fasttreeshap
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

# classes
model = RandomForestClassifier()
scl = StandardScaler

# Explainer
explainer = fasttreeshap.TreeExplainer(model=model,n_jobs=-1,algorithm="v0")

# shape values
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(scl.fit_transform(x_test))

# Plot
fasttreeshap.summary_plot(shap_values[0],x_test)
```